# Errors in youtubeplayersupportfragment in viewpager

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, layout-inflater, android-youtube-api

**It would be great if you guys could help me with this.

There are errors coming when i build the project, it's a NULLPOINT exception. 
I am unable to initialize the youtube player in the FRAGMENT (F2) and the fragment is used in Viewpager , which we can see in MainActivity java file**

Main Activity- MainActivity.java -> Layout -> activty_main.xml

Fragment CLASS-> F2.java -> Layout -> f2.xml

Console output is in the file- console output

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: It is unclear what you want, there is no question, no explanations. But a thank you :)

Comment: There is errors coming when i Build the project, its NULLPOINT exception

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(java.lang.String, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer$OnInitializedListener)' on a null object reference
            at learning.appdemo.F2.onCreateView(F2.java:161)
            at learning.appdemo.F2.onCreateView(F2.java:31)

Comment: I am unable to initialize the youtube player in the FRAGMENT (F2) and the fragment is used in Viewpager , which we can see in MainActivity java file

Comment: Okay, now **edit your question**! :)